# databinder for wicket concept & status

Tags: java, hibernate, web, wicket, databinder

Seems like Wicket + DataBinder(https://github.com/wicket-databinder/wicket-databinder) is good solution if you know only plain java and need to write data-driven web app, as i am.  But when i use auth functionality of dataBinder i gain error - when i register new user my password and confirm password not match. I look into the code - getConvertedInput() of RSAPasswordTextField return some long Base64 and it's different for password fields. I don't find databinder auth examples on net. Question and thought:

1. What is the common way of using current version of DataBinder? For example, how i can use net.databinder.auth.components.hib.DataSignInPage?
2. There is many todo comments in databinder. What of databinder features is stable?
3. I like that common web functionality is already in databinder, so i don't need reinvent the wheel. Maybe there is more actual alternative for that?

Otherwise i can contribute to databinder. Anyway i need to develop my application, so i can start from that is already in databinder. But i need status of modules(what works and how to use/what not work and what to do). Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today databinder have no contributors. I write to Fausto Bencosme (he was the last). We try to use DataBinder together, but few problems occur. Fausto recommend to use Ebean. I try - looks like it works. So for newbies i recommend Ebean to.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Nathan (author of databinder) has moved on to scala development, and databinder has since been stuck. Your best avenue is to contact Nathan, or one of the 10 forks  on github to see how you can reignite development of databinder.

1. As I don't use databinder, I can't answer this one
2. I'd see the todo comments as a good pointer to where you can pick up maintaining the code base
3. There are [several libraries that integrate with Wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/related-projects-and-tools.html) in various forms of maintenance.

Comment: Thank you Martijn! I found that some common data-driven tasks already done by databinder. For example user auth. I just add link to  DataBinder's SignInPage and signIn/register tasks is done. Only one trouble - registaration ends up with errors. I search throught wicket projects and don't find alternatives. What advanced wicket developers use for such tasks?